# Rest service returns "The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type."

Tags: json, rest, webclient, media-type

I can connect successfully  to the rest service over POSTMAN , but i have an error returning from webservice when i try using WebClient in .Net .

Error from service:  'The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.'

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            // Request configuration            
            client.Headers.Add("X-Signature", signature);
            client.Headers.Add("Api-Key", apiKey);
            client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("Media-Type", "application/json");  

            // Request execution
            string response = client.DownloadString(endpoint);
            string r = client.UploadString(hotelDetailsEndpoint, inputJson);



        }
```